# Language independent way of checking timezone in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm testing our infrastructure using the powershell command:

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id
```

Which returns a string like

```
Eastern Standard Time
```

Our servers are all english right now, but I'm pretty sure this test would fail if I ran it on a non-english windows.

Is there a way to check the timezone without having to check it against an English string?

Comment: AFAIK, `Id` property of `TimeZoneInfo` class is not localized. At least on my not English PC all of time zones have English `Id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id` use `[System.Timezoneinfo]::Local.BaseUtcOffset` which will give you the result in terms of the number of hours difference between UTC time and the timezone of the server you are working with.

**EDIT**

@LotPings is correct that the BaseUtcOffset will not take into account DST, which may not matter if you are only concerned with verifying the timezones have not changed from your standard but if it is important you can instead use `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.GetUtcOffset($(get-date))` which will get you the current UTC offset.

Comment: But this info is not complete, It doesn't tell you about DST and if DST is in effect now/at the date-time asked.

Comment: your correct, I still think that's the best approach to use here to verify time zones have not been changed but I've added code to get the current offset rather than the base if that is needed.